Stream Telethon media download to upload POST endpoint
I am trying to write a script in Python that downloads some media file from a channel and then uploads it to another location using a POST endpoint.
I am using the Telethon library to download said media file from Telegram. The issue I currently have is that, the file size is about 1Gb in size, and I'd like to stream the download directly to the upload instead of storing it in memory or in file. As far as I am aware, Telethon only allows you to download into memory or into a file.
This is the code I'm currently working with.
# Get last 10 messages from the channel
async def get_last_messages():
    global pbar
    global prev_curr
    async for message in client.iter_messages(channel_id, limit=10):
        if re.search(pattern, message.text) and message.media:
            print('Downloading media...')
            prev_curr = 0
            pbar = tqdm(total=message.document.size, unit='B', unit_scale=True)
            await message.download_media(file='./media/', progress_callback=callback)
            pbar.close()
            print('Media downloaded.')


I've no idea how to progress regarding this particular requirement of mine. Any input would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
